# zebra printer provide keyboard_input for design label in ZPL payload

Tags: printing, barcode, zpl

I use the printer zebra printer model `zd410` and have designed a label with some keyboard inputs that I want to provide in a ZPL payload, instead of using their software for actually filling out a formula since we already have the data from the application that should print the labels.
The label has these 4 `Variable keyboard input` with following prompt texts.

- barcode = text
- reservation = text
- department = text
- size = text

So by sending

```
LABEL.ZPL^XA
^XFE:LABEL.ZPL^FS
^XZ
```

I can print a label with the empty values. I was hoping that I could fill them out by doing something like:

```
LABEL.ZPL^XA
^XFE:LABEL.ZPL^FS
^department=M3
^size=XL
^reservation=0008734
^barcode=000000000001
^XZ
```

However this does not work, I was wondering  how one would achieve something similar.

Comment: You have read the description of the Zebra tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is possible, but requires the recalled format to contain "placeholders" where the data is to be displayed.  In the `E:LABEL.ZPL` format, you need to define numbered fields like:

```
^FO150,125^A0N,36,20^FN1^FS
```

Where the `^FN1^FS` is the placeholder for the field #1 data.  The `^FN#^FS` can be placed in the format anywhere you would normally put a `^FD...^FS` data field (text and barcode data).

Then you recall the format and supply the data for the placeholder using:

```
^XA
^XFE:LABEL.ZPL^FS
^FN1^FDMY VALUE^FS
^XZ
```

That will substitute `^FDMY VALUE^FS` for any occurrences of the `^FN1^FS` placeholder in the recalled format.